# Unable to locate tomcat log file

Tags: log, tomcat6

I am not able to locate the tomcat log files on ubuntu. I looked into `/var/log/tomcat6` but the output are these file,

```
catalina.2012-11-23.log  catalina.out       localhost.2012-11-23.log
catalina.2012-11-24.log  catalina.out.1.gz  localhost.2012-11-24.log
```

Any idea which is the correct one?

Comment: just try it to find using `find` command. here how to use: `sudo find / -type f | grep tomcat| grep log` Reply what happens..

Comment: Catalina.out is typically where it will write application startup/shutdown/error output but you'll need to check the tomcat6/conf directory for the various .conf files. This is where the log file paths are defined.

Answer (score 2):

I usually find any files using `file` command and filter the results using `grep`. It helps on many situation. For your case it is possible that your `tomcat6` log file would be located in some other place.

So you can use following command to locate it, you would get few results then it would be easier to look the actual path:

```
sudo find / -type f | grep tomcat| grep log
```

For example if I want to find all the `log` files of `apache2` then I have to execute this (I don't have tomcat installed, so giving apache2 example):

```
sudo find / -type f | grep apache2 | grep log
```

I got this:

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log.7.gz
/var/log/apache2/error.log.1
/var/log/apache2/error.log.9.gz
/var/log/apache2/error.log.3.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.1
/var/log/apache2/error.log.6.gz
/var/log/apache2/error.log.7.gz
/var/log/apache2/error.log
/var/log/apache2/error.log.2.gz
/var/log/apache2/error.log.5.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.2.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.4.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.9.gz
/var/log/apache2/error.log.8.gz
/var/log/apache2/error.log.4.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.6.gz
/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
/var/log/apache2/access.log.8.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log.5.gz
/var/log/apache2/access.log
/var/log/apache2/access.log.3.gz
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_log_forensic.so
/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-bin/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/apache2-utils/changelog.Debian.gz
/etc/apache2/mods-available/log_forensic.load
/etc/apache2/conf.d/other-vhosts-access-log
/etc/logrotate.d/apache2
```

Now it is easier to locate all log of apache2 like `error` , `access` etc.. You can use more filter to cascade some more results..

Hope you would be able to locate your `tomcat6 log` file..

Answer (score 1):

Catalina.out is the file you are looking for.
In order to view log on terminal , you can use 


`tail -f /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out`